# Richfaces, sortable datatable, sort icons

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

is there a way to change the sort icons of the datatable?

I know, it is possible to set the tag attribute `sortIcon` for the `rich:column` but this only replaces the icon which is set at the generated `<img>` tag. There seems no way to change the align of this img or the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the css class `.rich-sort-icon`.

For example try playing with the `float` css attribute.

Comment: Which doesn't affects the positioning of the img tag. The tag is always placed after the column text.

Comment: try playing with the `float` attribute and you will probably find ways ;)

Comment: Meh this is a little bit naughty but ok. Thought there would be a "nicer" way :) Thanks Bozho

Comment: Naughty? CSS is there for styling :) HTML is just markup. Oh, you forgot to accept his answer.

Comment: Styling a tag element to be placed before an other element instead of switching tag positions is naughty for me yes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Icon images can be changed through *sortIconAscending*, *sortIconDescending* and *sortIdon* attributes of the [rich:column](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_column.html) tag.

The disadvantage is that this has to be done for every single column that has sorting.  However, an abstraction facelet may be created that contains these attributes.

Then css class *rich-sort-icon* can be used to style where the first thing should be resetting height and weight to auto.

Removing of the default sort icon is not possible on Richfaces 3.3. A transparent image can be used to "remove" it.